# New 12.04.1 ISO filename

Tags: iso, yumi

I use a program called yumi from [pendrivelinux.com](http://pendrivelinux.com) to load all my Linux distros from a USB thumbdrive. They just updated their installer to support the newest 12.04.1 released a couple days ago.

It's looking for a ISO name of `ubuntu-12.04.*dvd-i386.iso` but the file I downloaded from the Ubuntu homepage is named `ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-i386.iso`.  Can I simply change the name of my ISO, or is there a difference in the ISO?

Comment: yes you can sir... no problem with that.

Comment: Won't hurt if you try to rename and test it.

Answer (score 0):

You can sure. Rename does NOT hurt the contents of your ISO.